# How to Synchronise(update) Windows and Web Application Databases

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having an application in both windows and web domains.The web part of it have only limited features compared to it's windows counterpart.But for my case (an appointment fixing module which is done using both domains),I want both databases to update with the other database.Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can create some trigger logic to do updations.

2.You could create a seperate exe or service that polled both databases
    based on some key like lastupdated
    and synchroized data.

All this is based on your data/table structure and how it is entered and structure.